# How to plot the difference of the date times in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have measured values in different times and I would like to plot them.
In the excel file the columns are separated  for the time and for the values. The time format is : HH:MM:SS e.g:11:20:21.
I wolud like to plot on the x axis the diferrence between the times (in seconds).The y axis would be the measured values. I read the datas from the excel file but don't know how to plot the x axes.
For example: datas in excel:10:20:33,10:20:35,10:20:39 and on the x axes the values are:0,2,4 (in seconds).
Here is my start:

```
V1= xlsread('measured.xlsx','D4:D5295')
V2= xlsread('measured.xlsx','E4:E5295')
CV= xlsread('measured.xlsx','F4:F5295')
t=xlsread('measured.xlsx','B4:B5295')

plot(t,V1,t,V2,t,CV)
 datetick('x',13)
title('Measurement')
ylabel('Data [V]')
xlabel('time [s]')
```

With this I get on the x axis date but I would like to get the elapsed time between two measuretime.

Answer (score 0):

What I will do is convert the time vector to "datatime" data type, calculate the difference between the times (using the diff command) and then convert it to seconds.

```
V1= xlsread('measured.xlsx','D4:D5295')
V2= xlsread('measured.xlsx','E4:E5295')
CV= xlsread('measured.xlsx','F4:F5295')
t=xlsread('measured.xlsx','B4:B5295')
% convert it to datatime data type
t = datetime(t); 
% Get the difference between times and add the "0" to keep 
%   the same vector size.
t = [0; seconds(diff(t))];

plot(t,V1,t,V2,t,CV)
 datetick('x',13)
title('Measurement')
ylabel('Data [V]')
xlabel('time [s]')
```

Comment: I received' Error using datetime 
Numeric input data must be a matrix with three or six columns, or else three, six, or seven separate numeric arrays. You can also create
datetimes from a single numeric array using the 'ConvertFrom' parameter.'

Comment: What is the data type of the "t" variable? I assumed it was string or char. If it is numeric (11:05:22), can you try to read the table using the readtable function instead of the xlsread?

Comment: Yes the datas are like 11:05:22,I tried t=readtable('measured.xlsx','B4:B5295'); and it says 'Error using readtable (line 198)
All parameters must have an associated value.;'

Comment: Exactly what format are the dates in in Excel? If they're standard date-formatted cells, you probably need to use Matlab's `x2mdate` function to convert Excel serial dates to Matlab datetime values.